# Change wingpanel color

Tags: wingpanel

Is there a way to keep the wingpanel color minimized and maximized as the same? Because when any app is maximized, the wingpanel color changes to black background and doesn't keep as when wasn't maximized.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. If it doesn't exist, create one.

Write in a gtk.css file:

```
.panel {
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.panel.maximized {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

It will make wing panel transparent in maximized mode. Don't forget to reboot your PC after changings! Or use `killall wingpanel` on Terminal to kill the wingpanel process. It will automatically restart.